# How can I get contact first name and last name in the same column?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get contact first name and last name in the same column as shown in the picture?
Here  is my incomplete query:

```
SELECT
    customernumber,
    customername,
    contactfirstname,
    contactlastname
FROM
    dbs211_customers
WHERE
    country = 'Canada'
ORDER BY
    customernumber;
```

Here is the link for img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e5C2.png

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, you need to include a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as the answer to the question depends on knowing that - syntax and functionality varies between them.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask a Good SQL Question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and then come back and [edit] your post to provide the relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi one way you can try is as follows.

```
SELECT
    customernumber,
    customername,
    contactfirstname || ' , ' ||  contactlastname
FROM
    dbs211_customers
WHERE
    country = 'Canada'
ORDER BY
    customernumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

just use concatenation

```
SELECT customernumber, customername, CONCAT(conctractfirstname, ' ', contractlastname) as `contract_fullname` FROM dbs211_customers WHERE country = 'Canada' ORDER BY customernumber;
```

Comment: CONCAT doesn't exist in all DBMSs, and the OP has given no information about the DBMS that is being used.

Answer (score 0):

There's no picture shown in your question.

But assuming you're asking for something like this:

```
SELECT customernumber,
(contactfirstname + ' ' + contactlastname) AS ContactFullName
FROM dbs211_customers
WHERE country = 'Canada'
ORDER BY customernumber;
```

Comment: `+` does not work for concatenation on all DBMSs, and the OP has not identified which DBMS is being used.

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL developer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    customernumber,
    customername,
    concat(concat(contactlastname, ', '), contactfirstname) as "Contact Name"
FROM
    dbs211_customers
WHERE
    country = 'Canada'
ORDER BY
    customernumber;
```